What is the significance of the UK "entry clearance vignettes" with the retirement of the BRPs?
Previously the process for using a long-term UK residential visa was:

You obtain your visa that is valid for several years
In your passport, you get an entry clearance sticker that is valid only for 90 days
You must enter the UK within those 90 days, even though your visa is valid for years
You must collect your Biometric Residence Permit (BRP), after which you are allowed to exit and re-enter the UK as you please at any time. The official guidance would emphasize the importance of collecting the BRP and point out that one would not be able to easily re-enter the UK if they leave without collecting the BRP.

This was understandable and straightforward.
However, the BRPs are being retired and replaced by eVisas. New BRPs are no longer issued, so there is nothing to collect after one's initial entry to the UK.
Still, people keep getting the same entry clearance stickers, valid for 90 days only, when applying for their long-term visas, as this answer suggests, and as I can confirm because I am looking at one right now.
What I don't quite understand is

Why do these entry clearances exist, provided that there is nothing to collect or do in the UK to "consummate your stay", so to say. If you have been issued one, that means you have an eVisa already, which any border control officer will immediately see on their computer; and
Is it actually important to observe them and to make your initial entry within the allocated 90 days only.

I have two cases in point that I have personally witnessed.

October 2024. The person with an entry clearance vignette made their way to the UK border within the allotted 90 days, which was very inconvenient for them for an unexpected change in personal circumstances. The border control officer said he did not want to see the entry clearance vignette, check its expiry date, or have anything to do with it at all, because he can see the eVisa on his computer that is valid for the many years. He said he wouldn't even stamp the entry vignette with an entry stamp, unless the person would specifically like that for their records.
This person had had a BRP issued for them, and needed to collect it.

January 2025 (not happened yet). The person has an entry clearance vignette that is valid for 90 days starting on 01/01/2025. The decision letter instructed them not to collect the BRP because there isn't one, but still imposed the 90 day entry window.


Is this 90 day window actually of any importance as of now?
Does it actually need to be observed (as the Person 1's experience suggests otherwise), or is it bureaucratic remains of the BRP-centered process?
Do border control officers actually ignore these entry clearances on a regular basis, or was it a fluke?

The fact that the officer didn't need to see the vignette in person 1's experience doesn't necessarily mean there's no time limit. The 90-day window dates are probably in the eVisa and visible to the officer. I suppose the whole point may be that if you don't come within the 90-day window, your circumstances may have changed quite a bit (especially the reason for the residence permit to be granted), so they want to make sure you do come within that window (which is already quite long to account for small changes in circumstances).

@jcaron I would (perhaps wildly) guess that the need to visit within the 90-day window also helps discourage "speculative" visa applications from someone might want to enter "some time" during a visa's validity, but hasn't yet got firm plans.
